# Unable to edit powerpoint XML data points

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I'm utilizing python to update data within the xml below, what im trying to do in all is update text within a powerpoint dynamically using an incoming dataframe, by doing so i pull out the xml from the pptx file and can't figure out how to change the text within the xml.

Dataframe:

```
   Old            New
0  A.1      Valuation
1  A.2          12000
2  A.3           5.23
3  A.4  Test,Complete
```

XMLFile: [Github Link](https://github.com/daimian166/XML-Files/blob/571c331b77d8784a9594d9b7a77bb4e142a618b0/slide1.xml)

XML Snippit:

```
                                                        <a:tc>
                                                            <a:txBody>
                                                                <a:bodyPr/>
                                                                <a:lstStyle/>
                                                                <a:p>
                                                                    <a:pPr algn="l" fontAlgn="auto"/>
                                                                    <a:r>
                                                                        <a:rPr lang="en-US" sz="1800" dirty="0">
                                                                            <a:effectLst/>
                                                                        </a:rPr>
                                                                        <a:t>A.1​</a:t>
                                                                    </a:r>
                                                                    <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1800" b="0" i="0" dirty="0">
                                                                        <a:solidFill>
                                                                            <a:srgbClr val="000000"/>
                                                                        </a:solidFill>
                                                                        <a:effectLst/>
                                                                        <a:latin typeface="Calibri" panose="020F0502020204030204" pitchFamily="34" charset="0"/>
                                                                    </a:endParaRPr>
                                                                </a:p>
                                                            </a:txBody>
                                                            <a:tcPr/>
                                                        </a:tc>
```

Python Code:

```
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
import lxml.etree as ET
import pandas as pd


xml_file = r'\Desktop\PowerPoint XML\Test\ppt\slides\slide1.xml'
Dataframe = r'\Desktop\PowerPoint XML\Dataframe.xlsx'


df = pd.read_excel(Dataframe)

df['Old'] = df['Old'].astype(str)
df['New'] = df['New'].astype(str)

# open xml file that contains slide data

tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
treeRoot = tree.getroot()
rootString = ET.tostring(treeRoot)
decodedRootString = bytes.decode(rootString)
old = df.Old; new = df.New


# search for old value then replace with new

for elem in treeRoot.iter():
    elem.text.replace(old[elem],new[elem])

FinalString=str.encode(decodedRootString)

#save the XML File
root = ET.fromstring(FinalString)
my_tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
with open(xml_file, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(ET.tostring(my_tree))
```

Error Log:

```
  File "\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 36, in <module>
    elem.text.replace(old[elem],new[elem])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```